# GTK Window configure events not propagating

Tags: c++, c, events, gtk

I'm attempting to capture an event on a GTK window when the window is moved.  I'm doing so with something that looks like this:

```
void mycallback(GtkWindow* parentWindow, GdkEvent* event, gpointer data)
{
    // do something...
}

...
GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);    

gtk_widget_add_events(GTK_WIDGET(window), GDK_CONFIGURE);
g_signal_connect_(G_OBJECT(window), "configure-event", G_CALLBACK(mycallback), NULL);
...
```

This works- the event is properly called when the window is moved... but it's also called when the window is resized.  This has the side effect of not resizing the window's sub-elements as they would if I didn't connect the event.

According to [this table](http://developer.gnome.org/doc/GGAD/sec-gdkevent.html#TAB-WIDGETEVENTS) in the GTK docs, the GDK_CONFIGURE event does not propagate.  If the event does not propagate, how can I still detect the window's movement while allowing it to resize properly?

note: I'm using GTK version 2.12.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luke, as you have discovered, returning FALSE allows the event to propagate. This is explained in the gtk tutorial [here](http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut-2.html)

Answer (score 2):

Neuro- I didn't believe that would work because the function signature returned void rather than gboolean.  For grins, I changed:

```
void mycallback(GtkWindow* parentWindow, GdkEvent* event, gpointer data)
```

to

```
gboolean mycallback(GtkWindow* parentWindow, GdkEvent* event, gpointer data)
```

I would have thought this would cause a type-mismatch with the callback types, but it does not.  Returning TRUE like you suggested doesn't work... but strangely returning FALSE does.  This being the case, it appears that the event *can* propagate.

---

**Edit:**

According to the [GTK tutorial](http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk%5Ftut-2.html) (thanks Matt):

> The value returned from this function
>   indicates whether the event should be
>   propagated further by the GTK event
>   handling mechanism. Returning TRUE
>   indicates that the event has been
>   handled, and that it should not
>   propagate further. Returning FALSE
>   continues the normal event handling.

Comment: It won't cause a type mismatch because of the cast to `G_CALLBACK`, but there **needs** to be a value returned, as I think it's UB to call a `void` function here and not supply the expected return value, meaning that a fake boolean will be read off some unrelated part of the stack, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I mainly use gtkmm (C++ wrapper of GTK). But if I recall correctly, if you want to propagate the signal to the parent, your handler should return FALSE (gint), meaning "I have NOT handled this event". So I think that if you return *(gint)FALSE* in *mycallback*, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you will *not* get type mismatch error for signal handlers, because in gtk you cast them all to the same type using G_CALLBACK regardless of their actual signature. The signature is declared dynamically at run-time in a GObject's class_init function, so there is no way to type check them statically. You *MUST* consult the documentation for the signal you are interested in and make sure that the handlers signature matches the signal's signature.

Comment: Both interesting, and annoying.  I'm sure they have *a* reason to subvert type safety like that, but I can't say it sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: This should have been a comment on Luke's answer, not a post. @luke Surely the reason they use type-erasure is because otherwise they would have to declare and implement an arbitrary number of overloads, storage structures, etc for every possible function pointer. Impractical, at best.